# Cite a Powerpoint Presentation

Tags: citation, mla

I'm writing my Junior paper and found several powerpoint presentations online. Now, I'm working on the bibliography and my English teacher doesn't know how to cite them and every site I've visited has provided a different response. Anybody know the standard, accepted method? Because, the last time I checked, MLA doesn't provide one.

For example, [this powerpoint](http://www.sequim.k12.wa.us/151920831173212473/lib/151920831173212473/The_Charge_of_the_Light_Brigade.ppt).

Comment: You cannot find a “powerpoint”.

Comment: Of course you can. You can find anything with Google *;)*

Comment: You mean a Powerpoint ***presentation***.

Comment: I suppose I do. I apologize for the miscommunication :(

Comment: If you're going to use the name of the software, and it's Microsoft's software, please spell it PowerPoint.

Comment: This question appears to be another citation question suitable for Writers.SE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I visited the Purdue OWL, where they provide much [MLA Works Cited guidance](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/09/).  I did not find any guidance specific to PowerPoint presentations, but I did find this:

[image]

The example file you point to has no author information available on the slides.  In PowerPoint, you can use `File > Properties` to check for author information, but that information might only provide a clue, and should by no means be considered reliable (it's more likely to contain information related to the owner of the computer that the file was last saved on, rather than information about the originator of the intellectual content.  For example, in the file you reference, the Author is listed as "jru" and the file was last saved by G. Pringle. The file's Properties information also reveals that the file was created in 2008 and last saved in 2010.).

MLA [no longer requires a web address](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/08/), but, a URL is not prohibited, either.  With so little information available for this citation, you might want to provide one anyway:

```
"The Charge of the Light Brigade." 2010. Web. Microsoft PowerPoint file. 
<http://www.sequim.k12.wa.us/151920831173212473/lib/151920831173212473/
The_Charge_of_the_Light_Brigade.ppt>
```

Based on the information available, that's how I'd cite it.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint artifacts are typically used as visual aids during presentations. The citation would refer for the presentation where it was used, not the .ppt(x) file itself, so whatever citation you would use to cite a person presenting would be appropriate.

Comment: That may be the original intended use, but unfortunately some organisations use them for sharing information to be read without a presentation. And in this case, the file was found on the internet via Google without having attended a presentation.